# AWS metrics: Your search - billing - did not match any metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new into aws and I need to set up some metrics (using aws cloudwatch) but when I try to filter and show metrics (I need to add the `Total Estimated Charge` matric) but I always get this error: `Your search - billing - did not match any metrics.`

Here is the screenshot:
[image: Your search - billing - did not match any metrics.]

How can I get the `Total Estimated Charge` metric?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Billing metrics are located in `us-east-1` region.

Make sure the Console is switched to that region by selecting `US East (N. Virginia) us-east-1` in the region selector (top right corner, next to **Support** button).

Once you switch the region, you can:

- Search for the metric, like you did.
- Browse the metrics in the **Metrics** page (select **Metrics** left pane).
- Go to CloudWatch homepage (select **CloudWatch** on the left pane) and there you should see a link to the default billing dashboard. This direct link should get you there, if you're logged in the account (make sure to select a wider time range, billing metrics are emitted every 6 hours): https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#cw:dashboard=Billing

Comment: If Billing metrics is located in us-east-1, if my services are on us-esat-2 should i still be able to see the billing metrics for services in us-east-2 from the us-east-1 dashboard?

Comment: Dashboards can show metrics from different regions (different accounts even). So once you have your metric on the dashboard, you can see it regardless of the region. It's only on the Metrics page where you need to filter for the region to find the metric.

Comment: The problem im having is billing metrics are only being shown for us-east-1 and not us-east-2